# Java client throws SocketException: Connection reset when receiving data from C server. Why?

Tags: java, c, sockets, java-io

I have a TCP/IP server program written in C and a corresponding client written in Java:

**C Server**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>


#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#define PORT 0

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


    printf("ISV_APP: Initiating TCP/IP networking.\n");

    int server_fd, new_socket, valread;
    struct sockaddr_in address;
    int opt = 1;
    int addrlen = sizeof(address);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};



    // Creating socket file descriptor.
    if((server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM,0)) == 0)
    {
        printf("TCP/IP: Initiation of server socket file descriptor failed.\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    printf("TCP/IP: Initializing server socket.\n" );

    // Forcefully attaching socket to the connection port.
    if(setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR | SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt)))
    {
        printf("TCP/IP: Error with setsockopt call occured.\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    address.sin_port = htons(PORT);
    printf("TCP/IP: Socket options have been set.\n" );

    // Binding the socket.
    if(bind(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(address)) <0){
        printf("TCP/IP: Failed to bind socket.\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    printf("TCP/IP: Socket bound to port.\n" );

    // Listen for connections
    if(listen(server_fd, 3) < 0){
        printf("TCP/IP: Failed to listen for incoming connections.\n" );
        return -1;
    }

    // Print the assigned port and address so that client knows how to connect.
    struct sockaddr_in sin;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(sin);
    if (getsockname(server_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, &len) == -1){
        printf("Failed to read port number.\n" );
    }
    else{
        // Print port
        unsigned int my_port = ntohs(sin.sin_port);
        char my_port_str[6]; 
        sprintf(my_port_str, "%d", my_port);
        printf("\nINFO: Socket bound to port: " );
        printf(my_port_str);
        printf("\n");

        // Print address
        char my_ip[16];
        inet_ntop(AF_INET, &sin.sin_addr, my_ip, sizeof(my_ip));
        printf("INFO: Server IP Address: ");
        printf(my_ip);

        printf("\n");
        printf("\nServer is listening for incoming connections...\n" );

    }

    // Accept connection
    if((new_socket = accept(server_fd, (struct sockaddr*)&address, (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0){
        printf("TCP/IP: Failed to accept incoming connection.\n" );
        return -1;
    }
    printf("TCP/IP: Connection successfully established.\n" );
    printf("\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    // Connection successful. You can send and receive data now. 


    // Get message from client.
    printf("Waiting for message from client...\n");
    valread = read(new_socket, buffer, 1024);
    printf("FROM CLIENT: %s\n", buffer);

    // Pass message to client.
    printf("Sending message to client...\n");
    char *hello = "serversayshello";
    send(new_socket, hello, strlen(hello), 0);
    printf("Hello message sent\n");


    // Close file descriptors and end program.
    close(new_socket);
    close(server_fd);
    printf("End of program.");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Java Client**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class MobileClientPrototype {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        // Used to get user input. 
        BufferedReader inFromUser = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.print("Please enter IP Address:");
        String host = inFromUser.readLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter port number:");
        int port = Integer.parseInt(inFromUser.readLine());

        // Initialize Socket
        Socket clientSocket = new Socket(host, port);

        // Streams for communication with server
        DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        // Ask user for string message which will be sent to server
        String sentence;
        System.out.print("\nPlease enter message:\n");
        sentence = inFromUser.readLine();

        // Send message to server
        outToServer.writeBytes(sentence + '\n');
        System.out.print("Message sent!\n\n");

        // Wait for response message from server        
        String responseSentence;
        System.out.print("Awaiting response...\n");
        responseSentence = inFromServer.readLine();
        // Print response
        System.out.println("RESPONSE FROM SERVER:\n" + responseSentence);

        // Close socket and end program
        System.out.print("\nTerminating connection...");
        clientSocket.close();
        System.out.print("\nEnd of program.");
    }
}
```

**Scenario**

I run both the server and the client programs on my local machine. With the client, I enter `127.0.0.1` as the IP and the port number printed by the server. When connection is established, you can enter a message with the client which will be sent to the server. Afterwards, the server responds with *serversayshello*.

It works fine with some short strings, for example, I can transmit *hello*:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbQe2.png)

However, with some longer strings, the client throws `SocketException: Connection reset` as soon as he receives the response from the server.

Here, I am trying to send *hello from client* to the server. This is what happens:

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNYKy.png)

It is also worth noting that the server apparently does not receive the full message, as it only printed *hello from*.

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at MobileClientPrototype.main(MobileClientPrototype.java:38)
```

The transmission seems to work with short strings like "hello", "123456", "foo", "bar", "g g" and so on.

Some strings that don't work are:
"Hello" (with uppercase H), "hello from client", "foobarfoobarfoobar".

Other than that, I haven't figured out a pattern yet.

What is causing the client to throw an Exception when he transmits these longer messages?

Comment: `read()` returns a `ssize_t`, not an `int`.  They're not the same.  `read()` also does not `NUL`-terminate a string value.

Comment: 'send(new_socket, hello, strlen(hello), 0);'....... 'responseSentence = inFromServer.readLine();'.   What line?

Answer (score 0):

You wont know for sure if `read()` returns everything in single call(unless you look at contents of the data that is read or the return value of `read()`), many a time it will return partial data and you will have to `read()` again to read the remaining data

Recommended way for sockets communication will be to decide what data to expect beforehand, you can decide to have fixed length data and keep calling `read()` till total bytes(add up the return value from read() call, when greater than zero it indicates number of bytes successfully read) read equals  the  fixed length you predecided or you can decide to expect a new line to indicate end of data and keep reading in loop till you receive `'\n'`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will certainly add this to my code. However, it still doesn't explain the exception.

Comment: You ***will*** 'know for sure'. `read()` returns a count of how many bytes were transferred. And `DataInputStream.readFully()` already exists, and so does `BufferedReadsr.readLine()`.

Comment: @EJP I am referring if he sent "foobarfoobarfoobar"from client , when read in server returns he wont know if it returned "foobarfoobarfoobar" or just "foo" when single read() call returns, so recommened to read in loop till all expected data is read

Comment: "keep calling read() till total bytes read equals the fixed length" is implying add up the count returned by read(), I will make it explicit in answer

Comment: I am referring to the fact that `read()` returns a count whereby he *will* know how much data was transferred. I already said all that. Don't feel like repeating it again.

Comment: @EJP I understood what you are saying, I added explanation in first line in answer, apparently that was leading to contradiction

Comment: 'Looki[ng] at the content' cannot possibly help unambiguously. For the third time, `read()` returns a count of bytes transferred, and taking note of that ls both necessary and sufficient. When you say 'leading to a contradiction' the word you are looking for is 'wrong'.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common causes of 'connection reset':

1. Writing to a connection that had already been closed by the peer.
2. Closing a connection without reading all the data that had been sent by the peer.

There are others, but these are the most common. Both are application protocol errors.

In your case the clue is that it works for short messages but not for long messages, and the reason is that although the Java code is sending a message delimited by a line terminator, you are only executing a single `read()` in the C code, and assuming that this will read the entire message. There is no guarantee of this stated anywhere in Posix or the TCP/IP RFCs.

If you are expecting a message deliminted by a line terminator, you have to keep reading until you get it. That's what Java's `readLine()` method does, and it is what you need to emulate in your C code.